# Pregunta con sentencia preparada buscador PHP SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quiero hacer un buscador que mediante un select y un campo de tipo texto busque datos en una tabla de productos, usando el valor del select como campo de la tabla a buscar y el texto como el registro de ese campo, esto es para poder buscar productos por un campo y valor concretos, ejecuto esta sentencia PREPARADA SQL `$sql="SELECT * FROM producto WHERE ?  LIKE ?";` y luego continuo con los pasos para hacer la consulta **que adjunto mas abajo**

Mi problema es que no muestra los datos ni siquiera entra al bucle while, y nose si es un error en la consulta, o algo que tenga que ver con tipos de datos ya que la funcion `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` recibe ss lo cual son strings.

```
$obj=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
$ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($obj,"ss",$campo_busqueda,$texto);

$ok=mysqli_execute($obj);


if($ok==false){
echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta preparada";
}else{
$ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($obj,$codigo_producto,$nombre,$gama,$dimensiones,$proveedor,$descripcion,$cantidade_en_stock,$precio_venta,$precio_proveedor);




while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($obj)){

    echo $codigo_producto." ".$nombre;
}



}
```

Comment: Código como texto, por favor. Nadie va a responer con imágenes para hacerte transcribir (con errores, incluso) y a muchos les gusta probar el código que falla para ayudar a depurarlo. Siempre puedes [edit] la pregunta y ajustar estas cosas. De paso, evitas las mayúsculas sostenidas para evitar que se lea como gritos. De paso, revisa los logs de PHP y añade a la pregunta cualquier log relacionado, error o mensaje que consideres relevante.

Comment: Tu instrucción SQL es errónea, no puedes incluir columnas incógnitas en las consultas preparadas. Dinos además, ¿qué valen tus variables? ¿Cuántas columnas arrojaría ese `SELECT`? Y, como ya señaló @Alfabravo, pon el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Arrojaría 9 columnas las cuales serian las 9 variables de la función mysqli_stmt_bind_result. ¿Y entonces como podría hacer un buscador por columna y por registro?

Comment: un detalle, es que la parte de la sql `WHERE ?  LIKE ?` (sin saber que valores tienes) puede llevarte problemas, porque en el like deberias utilizar comodines. Es muy probable que te este buscando como un =. La instruccion deberia ser algo tipo: `LIKE '%?%'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lees la doc, verás que no puedes usar columnas o nombres de tablas en la vinculación de consultas preparadas.

[La Nota en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) es bastante clara:

> #### Nota:
>
> Los marcadores únicamente son legales en ciertos lugares de las
> sentencias SQL. Por ejemplo, están permitidos en la lista de
> `VALUES()` de una sentencia `INSERT` (para especificar los valores de
> las columnas de una fila), o en una comparación en una cláusula
> `WHERE` para especificar un valor de comparación.
>
> Sin embargo, no están permitidos en identificadores (como nombres de
> tablas o columnas), en la lista de selección que nombra a las columnas
> a ser devueltas por una sentencia `SELECT`), o para especificar ambos
> operandos de un operador binario como signo igual `=`. La última
> restricción es necesaria debido a que sería imposible determinar el
> tipo de parámetro. En general, los parámetros son legales únicamente
> en sentencias de Lenguaje de Manipulación de Datos (DML), y no en
> sentencias de Lenguaje de Definición de Datos (DDL).

Prueba a cambiar la instrucción así:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM producto WHERE $campo_busqueda LIKE ?";
```

Y el `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` debe cambiar también:

```
$ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($obj,"s",$texto);
```

Asumo que `$texto` aplica para un `LIKE`, es decir, contiene ya los comodines y todo....

Por otra parte, tiene muy mala espina eso de re-usar `$ok` como resultado de todo  ¿?

Vamos a mejorar:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM producto WHERE $campo_busqueda LIKE ?";
if ( $obj=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql) ) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($obj,"s",$texto);
    if ( mysqli_execute($obj) ) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($obj,$codigo_producto,$nombre,$gama,$dimensiones,$proveedor,$descripcion,$cantidade_en_stock,$precio_venta,$precio_proveedor);
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($obj)){
            echo "$codigo_producto $nombre\n";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta preparada";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error preparando la consulta";
}
```